# Get the name of a list item created with purrr::map

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I retrieved a list of csv files with purrr::map and got a large list.

```
  csv_files <- list.files(path = data_path, pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
  all_csv <- purrr::map(csv_files, readr::read_csv2)
  names(all_csv) <- gsub(data_path, "", csv_files)
  return all_csv
```

**EDITED as suggested by @Spacedman**

I further need to process each tibble/data frame separately within the *process_csv_data* function.

```
purrr::map(all_csv, process_csv_data)
```

How to retrieve the name of a single item in the large list without for loop?

Comment: Like `names(all_csv)[42]` for example?

Comment: Also, use `basename(csv_files)` to get the file name part of the path. `gsub` fails if `data_path` is `"."`, which it was when I tried this.

Comment: @Spacedman Is it the reason for the downvote? As I said, I'm avoiding a for loop and therefore I shouldn't have an index to use the bracket operator [.

Comment: I think you should say *within the process_csv_data function* for clarity.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `map2`, as in this reproducible example:

```
> L = list(a=1:10, b=1:5, c=1:6)
> map2(L, names(L), function(x,y){message("x is ",x," y is ",y)})
x is 12345678910 y is a
x is 12345 y is b
x is 123456 y is c
```

the output of the list as `x` in the function gets a bit munged by `message`, but its the list element of `L`.

Comment: `imap` was devised to make these usages of `map2` sexier, your answer can be simplified into : `imap(L,~message("x is ",.x," y is ",.y))`

Comment: see also `lmap`, that allows you to loop on `list-elements` (sublists of length 1) : `lmap(L,~ {message("x is ",.x[[1]]," y is ",names(.x));return(list(NULL))})`

Answer (score 6):

You can take advantage of purrr to keep all the data in a single, nested tibble. That way each csv and processed csv remains linked directly with the appropriate csv-name:

```
csv_files <- list.files(path = data_path, pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)

all_csv <- tibble(csv_files) %>% 
    mutate(data = map(csv_files, read_csv2),
    processed = map(data, process_csv_data),
    csv_files = gsub(data_path, "", csv_files)) %>%
    select(-data)
```

Comment: This works fine but it's a bit hard to retrieve the data by `all_csv$processed$name_of_file`. Alternatively, you can create a list of tibbles that can be accessed directly: `all_csv <- list.files(path = data_path, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  map(read_csv) %>%
  setNames(csv_files)` So can get a file just by `all_csv$name_of_file`